# Unconnected Linearly Seperable Classification

Tags: machine-learning, classification, svm, supervised-learning, separation

Consider classifying something like the case shown below (exagerated syntetic example):

[image: Example]

If this were a task to classsify into 3 groups, (blue-left, red, blue-right), then a Linear Support Vector Machine would work great.

But this is not a classification into 3 groups, just into two (blue, red).
What classifiers can handle this?
is a SVM, or a varient there of, still viable?

Comment: A nonlinear SVM can handle this just fine. A linear model can't separate such data well.

Comment: I'ld like to be using a linar model, because nonlinar models are very slow when working with the amount of data I have (>50,000 points). According to sklearn documention the linear SVM from liblinear has linear time complexity, but the general nonlinear SVM from libsvm has quadratic time complexity.
I guess no Multi-linear SVM exists?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible to use an SVM for such data. In fact it could even be more extreme such as this:

[image]

[image source](http://ocw.metu.edu.tr/pluginfile.php/4885/mod_resource/content/0/svm.pdf)

An SVM handles this kind of data with an appropriate kernel which transforms the data into a higher dimensional space in which it is linearly separable.

Comment: You can do **anything** with an appropriate kernal, but what kind of kernal is appropriate? Polynomial? (I don't think so, but I don't know much about kernals).